# How does precompile work?

Tags: coldfusion, bytecode, coldfusion-10

Adobe ColdFusion Server comes with a precompile tool to parse and compile CFML temmplates (cfm, cfc) to Java bytecode. When I execute a precompilation, all templates are saved as `.class` files in `\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses\`. But how does CF work with them?

In CF Admin there is an option to "Save Class Files", so already compiled templates are re-used on server start. But how does this option affect precompiled templates? Are precompiled templates even considered then (since they are in the same folder)?

And how does CF handle these `.class` files? Are they load into memory and then compiled by the JVM to machine code? How does CF distinguish between old versions of templates and newer ones? Seeing how the folder can be as big as 1,000,000 files and several GB of data, I doubt there's any cleaning routine.

Background: We are running about 100 applications with about 1,000 templates per application. On server restart and bigger code changes (affecting like 100/1,000 templates * 100 applications), CF takes ages to recompile everything to a point where the whole server just hangs, because threads are blocked.

How can I utilize the precompile tool to prepare code changes and make CF respond faster?

Comment: Is this question regarding ColdFusion 10 (which is currently EOL)?

Comment: Yes, but it probably still works the same way in 2016 Release, I assume.